# Simular recebimento de ligação com aparelho no usb (adb shell Android)

Tags: android, shell

Gostaria de saber como fazer para simular o recebimento de uma ligação (Receber uma ligação) com o aparelho conectado via usb no **adb shell** do Android.

Preciso realizar alguns testes no aparelho físico, porém **não pode ser através do emulador**.

Não pode ser  pelo emulador,pois a máquina de desenvolvimento é muito limitada.
Não posso ligar para o aparelho , pois não tem número, o chip de teste é só 3g.

Comment: Simular uma ligação? você diz "chamar" o seu telefone? com que finalidade?

Comment: Porque não pode ser através do emulador?

Comment: Não bastaria ligar de um celular fixo para ele?

Comment: Esqueci de informar mais um detalhe, o aparelho só tem um chip 3g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível realizar ligações simuladas para um aparelho real. 
Para isto, infelizmente você precisará utilizar o emulador.

Answer (score 1):

Quando necessitei testar uma chamada em um aparelho físico eu apenas fiz uma ligação para o mesmo. Exemplo:

- O aplicativo está instalado e "debugando" no aparelho A.
- No aparelho B fiz uma ligação para o aparelho A.

Porem os teste era apenas para ver como o app se comporta quando houver uma ligação. Agora não sei se no seu caso é o mesmo, ou seu app é para trabalhar diretamente com a chamada, como gravar, pegar número de quem está ligando etc.

Comment: Esqueci de informar mais um detalhe, o aparelho só tem um chip 3g.
infelizmente o cenário é esse.